# Creating a database in my plugin not working

Tags: database, dbdelta

Good day everyone, I've been trying to add a table in my database for a whole day now, and I can't seem to find the error, I looked into multiple similar questions, but I had my syntax similar to all of them, and I followed the Codex when adding dbDelta().

```
<?php
if( !function_exists('transaction_draft_save') ){
//1, 234, donation, monday june 5 2018, give monthly, 10, usd, incomplete
function transaction_draft_save($user_id, $full_name, $email, 
$invoiceNumber, $plan_type, $date, $membership_type, $plan_price, $currency, 
$status){

    global $taylormemorial_options;
    global $wpdb;
    $dbprefix = '';
    $dbprefix = $wpdb->prefix;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix ."user_transactions";

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " . $table_name . " (
        'id' INT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
        'user_id' TEXT NOT NULL,
        'full_name' TEXT NOT NULL,
        'email' TEXT NOT NULL,
        'invoiceNumber' TEXT NOT NULL,
        'plan_type' TEXT NOT NULL,
        'date' TEXT NOT NULL,
        'membership_type' TEXT NOT NULL,
        'plan_price' INT NOT NULL,
        'currency' TEXT NOT NULL,
        'payment_method' TEXT NOT NULL,
        'status' TEXT NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
        )";

        dbDelta( $sql );


 }
}

?>
```

Another notice, is that Im calling this function in another page to pass the variables. If i return $sql variable and var_dump the function, it shows the query just fine, so scope is not the problem.
I checked once and twice and three times, but can't seem to find the root of the problem, if anyone can provide help, would really appreciate it and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax error. You don't need single quote for column name.

You can use phpmyadmin to test MySQL queries.

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name (
    id INT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    user_id TEXT NOT NULL,
    full_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    email TEXT NOT NULL,
    invoiceNumber TEXT NOT NULL,
    plan_type TEXT NOT NULL,
    date TEXT NOT NULL,
    membership_type TEXT NOT NULL,
    plan_price INT NOT NULL,
    currency TEXT NOT NULL,
    payment_method TEXT NOT NULL,
    status TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    )";
```

Comment: Its frustrating how simple the answer was, but thank you, you saved my life :D